# Is $(-2-2)^2 - (-2+3)(-2-3)-4(-2^2+2) = 69$?

Tags: arithmetic

I get 69 when I calculate this, but my calculator says it's 29. I've gone over this several times and can't figure out why I'm wrong. I'm also not entirely sure if I've used the calculator properly.

What answer is correct, and any idea where I'm heading wrong here?

Comment: Okay so $(-2-2)^2$ gives me $8$.
$-(-2+3)(-2-3)$ gives me $5$.
And $-4(-2^2+2)$ gives me $8^2-8$ which is $56$.

Add these together and I get $69$.

Comment: You didn't use the parentheses properly in the very first expression, $(-2-2)^2$ is not $8$.

Comment: I thought that gave me (4+4), am I supposed to solve the inside of the parantheses before I apply the exponentiation? Did not know that..

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of parentheses.

Comment: Also, It seems that you did like $-4\times (-2^2)=8^2$. This is wrong. Since $-2^2=-(2^2)=-4$, we have $-4\times (-2^2)=-4\times (-4)=16$.

Comment: Yeah it appears as if I've made the same mistake throughout the entire calculation.

I mean I did get the right answer for $-(-2+3)(-2-3)$ by simply adding both numbers with both numbers and not solving the parentheses first, which was $5$, but I guess it gets messed up once exponentials are involved.

Comment: No, it is the same principle: do everything inside the parentheses (which here is adding/subtracting both pairs of numbers) before doing the operation outside the parentheses (which here is either applying the unary minus or doing the multiplication, which can be done in either order with equal result).

Answer (score 1):

You have used you calculator properly. It is

$$(-2-2)^2=(-4)^2=16,$$ $$(-2+3)(-2-3)=1\cdot (-5)=-5,$$ and $$-4(-2^2+2)=-4(-4+2)=-4(-2)=8.$$ Thus, you get

$$16-(-5)+8=16+5+8=29.$$

Comment: $-2^2$ is the same as -2 ⋅ -2, right? So shouldn't that be 4 and not -4?

Comment: Nevermind, I guess multiplication>subtraction applies here as well..

Comment: Yes, if we want to express $(-2)^2$ we need parentheses to force the unary minus to be done first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your calculator is correct.

\begin{align*}
&(-2-2)^2-(-2+3)(-2-3)-4(-2^2+2)\\
&=(-4)^2-(1)(-5)-4(-4+2)\\
&=(16)-(-5)+16-8\\
&=16+5+16-8\\
&=21+8\\
&=29
\end{align*}
Note that $-2^2=-4$ whereas $(-2)^2=4$.